# How can I change the default Eclipse console?

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, eclipse-plugin, gdb

I'm using Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) a User Mode Linux kernel (4.2).

I really like to use Eclipse to debug it but with the default console we loose some features that exist in bash (e.g. command history with arrow up/down, folder path auto completion). Plus, Eclipse console can't handle ASCII color characters and even the plugins that I installed to do that can't handle all of them.

Is there a way to use another console (/bin/bash would be great) when debugging an application inside Eclipse?

Comment: When you say console, do you mean the terminal, or the actual 'Console View' ?

Comment: the actual console view

Answer (score 1):

The default console view in eclipse, is not designed to be a terminal (though you could make it act like one). Hence you wont get all the goodies that you just mentioned.

If it's a Shell to run terminal commands (linux based) that you are looking for, you could take a look at WickedShell plugin for eclipse: http://www.wickedshell.net/

Comment: I'm not at the computer right now to test it, but it doesn't look like you can integrate it as the debug console